# Replace repeating pattern regex

Tags: regex

I need to find and replace a repeating pattern in a string. More exacly, I need a string like:

```
Test - - - - - - - - - - - test
```

To become

```
Test - test
```

But since I don't know how many times the pattern is repeated, I fail to find an answer to it. The closest I got is:

```
((- -)|( - ))+?
```

But it fails on the example above.

Another "almost" result I had on:

```
([- ]+?)\1+
```

But the second one matches (and I don't want):

```
test   ---- test
```

Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: What about [this](https://regex101.com/r/Ko8Z7l/1)

Comment: Match `-(?: -)+` and replace with `-` https://regex101.com/r/hvRbYc/1

Comment: Maybe `(\s+-)+` with `$1`? See https://regex101.com/r/7iq53r/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
(\s-)+
```

Replace by `$1`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ko8Z7l/1)

Comment: Can't accept the answer yet, I will accept in 4 minutes.

Comment: Both answers worked (+1 to the other one also), yours was faster :).

Answer (score 2):

In the first pattern you tried `((- -)|( - ))+?` you get multiple matches making the quantifier `+?` non greedy.

In the second pattern `([- ]+?)\1+` the character class `[- ]+` is repeated which could match the same char multiple times.

---

You could match a single hyphen and repeat 1+ times matching a space and a hyphen to get a contiguous match without groups.

```
-(?: -)+
```

In the replacement use `-`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvRbYc/1/)